# Uncheck Checkbox when i use display "none" on some rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hei guys,
I am trying to change my Check All Button to only check the rows that are visible.
Unfortunately i am not seeing how i can address just the visible rows.
I tried something like this, but i didnt work out.

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    if(!x){
        if($(".check").is("visible")){
        $(':checkbox').each(function(){ this.checked = true; 

        });}

        x=true;}

    else{
        $(':checkbox').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
        x= false;
        }});
```

Thats how i filter my  table.

```
function abtFilter() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("searchbar");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("notfallTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            $("")
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and this is how the table looks like.

```
        items.push("<td class='numbers' contenteditable>"+val.Nummer+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Typ+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Vorname+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Nachname+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Abteilung+"</td>");

        items.push("<td class='check'><label><input type='checkbox'>"+""+"</input></label></td>");

        items.push("</tr>");
```

Greetings Elfdow

Comment: Try creating a minimal working example. Also, please try placing your code in a runnable snippet (inserted using `Ctrl + M`) so that we can see exactly what the problem is and what exactly that you want.

Comment: Hey. The answer below already works. But thanks for your effort. :D

Comment: Glad to know that you've received an answer. Nevertheless, always try to ask questions by mentioning the problem and the solution you want and also creating a minimal working example. It really helps you and potential answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:visible` selector on the checkboxes directly. Also note that you don't need an `each()` loop; you can set the `checked` property and jQuery will automatically loop through all the selected elements for you. Try this:

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', !x);
  x = !x;
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.